# Modify the results of an aggregate result directly

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

I need to add a variable to an Aggregate Result list.

In the semi pseudocode below I attempt to assign a value to the `AggregateResult[]` if the sum is 0.

This does not work.  The `aggRes` is later used in a function and I do not want to have to put the results of the aggregate result into a map for a solution.

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm doing and directly modify the `AggregateResult`?

```
AggregateResult[] aggRes = [Select Expense__c, Sum(Cost__c) from CustomObject__c Group By Expense__c]; 

for(AggregateResult ar: aggRes) {
    if(ar.get(Cost__c) == 0) {
        ar.put(Cost__c, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would it even mean to modify the `AggregateResult`, which represents more than just one record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you attempt to modify the AggregateResult, you'll get a runtime error. Here's an example from my dev org:

```
AggregateResult[] ar = [select name name from account group by name];
System.debug(ar[0]);
ar[0].put('name','Test2');
System.debug(ar[0]);
```

Result:

> EXECUTION_STARTED
>
> CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
>
> LIMIT_USAGE|[1]|SOQL|1|100
>
> LIMIT_USAGE|[1]|AGGS|0|300
>
> LIMIT_USAGE|[1]|SOQL_ROWS|69|50000
>
> ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|
>
> USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|AggregateResult:{name=,}
>
> ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|
>
> EXCEPTION_THROWN|[3]|System.SObjectException: Invalid field name for AggregateResult
>
> FATAL_ERROR|System.SObjectException: Invalid field name for AggregateResult

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query_aggregateresult.htm) also states that the object is read-only, so it is not possible to modify the values within the result object.

> AggregateResult is an sObject, but unlike other sObject objects such as Contact, it is read-only and it is only used for query results.

Comment: There is [documentation on this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query_aggregateresult.htm). Relevant exerpt: `AggregateResult is an sObject, but unlike other sObject objects such as Contact, it is read-only and it is only used for query results.` Based on that, this error is a bit misleading...but at least the reason why it errors out is documented.

Comment: @DerekF Thanks for the link! I had a feeling it was documented, I just wasn't sure where.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation it says *AggregateResult is a **read-only sObject** and is only used for query results.*

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm